# Extending A Function Periodically and Determining Whether Or Not It Converges

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I have a question that I'm not sure I'm understanding correctly, and require some assistance. The question reads:

> Consider the function defined on $[0,1)$:
>   $$f(x)=\begin{cases}-1 & \text{ if } 0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2}\\ 1 & \text{ if } \frac{1}{2}<x<1\end{cases}$$
>   Extend $f$ periodically with period $1$ to the entire real line. For each $n=1, 2, ...$, define $f_n(x)=f(nx)$. Now look at $f_n$ as a sequence of distributions. Does $f_n(x)$ converge as $n\rightarrow\infty$ in the sense of distributions? Now assume that $f$ is given by:
>   $$f(x) = \begin{cases}-1 & \text{ if } 0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2}\\ 5 & \text{ if } \frac{1}{2}<x<1\end{cases}$$
>   Repeat the above for this.

Now I know that for each $f_n(x)$, the distance of the period gets smaller and smaller, until it reaches $0$. So wouldn't the sequence $f_n$ for both cases just converge to $0$? If you integrated $f$ and took $n\rightarrow\infty$, the periods would get so small that the graph would technically turn into a vertical line, thus there would be no mass under it?

Am I approaching this question wrong? Is there something I'm not grasping?

Comment: The answer depends on what is meant by "look at $f_n$ as a sequence of distributions" and what the definition of "convergence in the sense of distirbutions" is.  Do you have a precise definition for that?  Then, you can determine whether or not your $f_n$ sequence of functions satisfies that definition.  I agree that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)dx=0$, can you prove that?

Comment: convergence in the sense of distributions is if the limit of: $$\int_{\mathbb R}f_n(x)\cdot\phi(x) dx$$ converges to some number, where $\phi(x)$ is some test function.

Comment: And I'm not even sure what f_n(x) would look like, I think the integral would look like:$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1 f_n(x) dx = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(-\int_0^\frac{1}{2n}dx+\int_{\frac{1}{2n}}^{\frac{1}{n}}dx\right)$$

Comment: Do you know what the test function $\phi$ is?  The test function that is $1$ if $x \in [0,1]$ and zero else would correspond to $\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx$.  The sequence $f_n(x)$ is just a $1/n$-periodic (compressed) version of the 1-periodic function $f(x)$.

Comment: Right... so then the sequence would just converge to $0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ no? Because the length of the domain of integration tends towards $0$? @Michael

Comment: For which test function?

Comment: We defined the test function to be a compact function with the property: $$<\delta_{x_0}, \phi> = \phi(x_0)$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67013/discussion-between-michael-and-felicio-grande).